# Gram-Schmidt procedure to construct an orthogonal basis for best approximation of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm using the Gram-Schmidt procedure to construct an orthogonal basis of
the $Span(1, x, x^3)$ for the interval [−1, 1]. I'm trying to determine the best approximation to $f(x) = x^5$.

$p(x) = c0*e0(x) + c1*e1(x) + c2*e2(x) + c3*e3(x) + c4*e4(x) + c5*e5(x)$

Where $c0 = <f,e0> / <e0,e0>$

In this case, is $e0(x) = 1, e1(x) = x, e2(x) = x^3$ ? Would I then use these to find $e3(x)$ to $e5(x)$?

For the inner product $<f,g>$, I am using $\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)dx$

Comment: What are you using for an inner product? The Gram-Schmidt process requires one.

Comment: $\mbox{span}(1, x, x^3)$ is 3-dimensional, so you could only hope for 3 orthonormal basis vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$. Then you should project $x^5$ onto $\mbox{span}(e_1, e_2, e_3)$.

Comment: I updated the question to specify what I'm using for an inner product

Comment: @JonWarneke for projecting $x^5$ onto $span(e1,e2,e3)$, do you mean expressing it as a linear combination of them, such as $(x*e2) * e3 = x^5$

Comment: First you need to orthonormalise $x \mapsto x^k$ ($k=0,1,2$) and then project $x \mapsto x^5$ onto this basis.

Comment: No -- if you could write $x^5 = c_1 e_1 + c_2 e_2 + c_3 e_3$, we wouldn't need an approximation. It would be exact! What you're looking for is the vector $v \in \mbox{span}(e_1, e_2, e_3) = S$ which is closest to the vector $x^5$ (which is NOT in $S$). By closest, we mean that $\|v - x^5\| \leq \|u - x^5\|$ for any $u \in S$. Of course, the norm $\| \cdot \|$ comes from the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ via $\| v \| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$, and the coefficients $v_i$ of $v = v_1e_1 + v_2e_2 + v_3e_3$ are from the projection formula $v_i = \langle x^5, e_i \rangle e_i$

Comment: Of course, you don't need Gram Schmidt, you could just solve $\min  \|x \mapsto x^5-(a+bx+cx^3) \|$ directly. This would give $a=0, b=-{5 \over 21}, c={10 \over 9}$, but then you would be missing all the fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $e_k$ are orthonormal, then
$\|f-\sum_k \alpha_k e_k \|^2 = \|f\|^2 -2 \sum_k \alpha_k \langle f, e_k \rangle + \sum_k \alpha_k^2$.

To find the best approximation, we minimise the above over the $\alpha_k$. This is a convex quadratic separable problem, and the solution is given by
just differentiating with respect to the $\alpha_k$. This gives
$\alpha_k = \langle f, e_k \rangle$.

Hence the best approximation is $\sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k$.

In the above problem, you are given $g_1(x) = 1, g_2(x) = x, g_3(x) = x^3$.
Use Gram Schmidt to orthonormalise the $g_k$ to get $e_k$. Then the 
coefficients $\alpha_k$ can be computed as above.

Here are the orthonormalised functions:
$e_1(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, $e_2(x) = \sqrt{3 \over 2} x$, 
$e_3(x) = \sqrt{7 \over 8}(5 x^3-3x)$.

Then for $f(x) = x^5$ we have $\langle f, e_1 \rangle = 0$,
$\langle f, e_2 \rangle = { \sqrt{6} \over 7}$, $\langle f, e_3 \rangle = {\sqrt{32} \over 9 \sqrt{7}}$.

Grinding through the details gives the best approximation
$\sum_k \langle f, e_k \rangle e_k = -{5 \over 21} x + {10 \over 9} x^3$.

[image]